# Different face for checked-off items in plain lists?

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

**Q:** how can I get a different face for checked-off items in `org` plain lists?

I use `org-mode`'s plain lists a lot:

```
- [X] item 1
- [ ] item 2
- [ ] item 3
- [ ] item 4, with a whole lot of text that makes this item
  span more than one line
```

The problem is that I find that the checkboxes do not give enough visual cues that I
have or have not completed an item.

*Is there a way to apply a
different face to checked-off list items (in the example, "item
1") while leaving the face alone for non-checked items?*

A built-into-org way to do so would be ideal, but if I need to
roll my own functionality, a complicating feature is that my items
often span more than one line (as with "item 4...").  How can I do this?

Comment: You can add an appropriate *checked-off* statement in `org-set-font-lock-defaults`, just beneath the existing statement relating to checkboxes at the section with the comment `;; Checkboxes`; and, perhaps modify the existing checkbox statement so that it *only* operates on *unchecked* items.  While modifying `org-set-font-lock-defaults` probably seems sacrilege, that is actually the proper way to do it (in my opinion, of course).

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you may also need to have a look at the section of code in `org-mouse.el` where it states `(when (memq 'activate-checkboxes org-mouse-features) ...`  Modifications at that location may be appropriate ...